# How to automatically log a users name in App Maker

Tags: directory, google-app-maker

I currently use the following onBeforeCreate to get a users email automatically logged into my data tables:

```
record.Email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

Is there a simple way to do this in onBeforeCreate event for the user name? I use the Directory Data Model to get my organisations user details. I've looked through various forum posts but can't seem to find what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using query filters and querying the directory model. Like this:

```
var query = app.models.[directoryModelName].newQuery();
query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var userName = query.run()[0].FullName;
```

That way if you have a field for the `fullName`, then all you have to add is:

```
record.fullName = userName;
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#querying_records